# Скидывает пароль на Mysl server'е

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, сервер, password

Установил Mysql server всё работало нормально и щас такие проблемы: поставил пароль свой, пару дней нормально заходит, а потом захожу и пароль видимо неправильный и закрывает окно, почему так?
Уже второй раз такая лажа, приходилось ставить заново, но всё равно неподходит потом пароль через пару дней.

Comment: Да веселится небось кто-то и меняет тебе пароль по-тихому...

Comment: Поддерживаю @Akina. Попробуй отрубить сеть физически от компа и посмотри сбросится пароль или нет.

Comment: Так как вы откатились к предыдущей версии, пожалуйста исправьте ошибки самостоятельно. Хорошего дня!

Comment: @donRumata имеешь ввиду отключить интернет? Но я не могу отключить его так и ждать - ведь он слетает в течение рандомного времени, это может быть в этот-же день или через месяц и т.д

Comment: Ну я не знаю других способов выяснить чё за фигня. Потому что мест, куда может пробраться шутник - дофигища.

Answer (score 1):

У паролей есть срок действия. Установите его на месяц. Будете не так часто менять.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/514826)

Comment: @V-Mor А какой вы можете предложить? Чем писать такой длинный комментарий, написали бы коротко по теме вопроса.

Comment: "такой длинный комментарий" сгенерирован автоматически из очереди проверок, о чём в нём, к слову, упоминается. Суть не в том, что я могу предложить, а в том, что Ваш ответ не содержит решения. Чтобы на это указать и был оставлен данный комментарий. Если остальные участники со мной не согласятся, Вашему ответу ничего не грозит.