# Слетает пароль в mysql server, что делать?

Tags: mysql

Короче, стоит виндовс 10 еще заводская - с покупки не меняли, поставил как-то mysql server и он время от времени слетает и приходиться заново ставить. Слетает - захожу, ввожу пароль и он закрывается. Раньше если не правильно ввести пароль он тоже закрывался, но закрывался сразу, а когда всё слетает то он думает сколько-то и потом закрывает окно. Что делать уже задолбался. Выключал инет и всё равно.
Вопрос уже задавал, но таки не помогло ничего.

Comment: В предыдущем вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807105/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-mysl-server%D0%B5 Вам уже все ответили. Кто-то из вашей сети меняет ваш пароль

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а как можно тогда это предотвратить?

Comment: Установить сложный пароль для пользователя root и никому не выдавать root права